# Connected_Slaves Metric When Using Slave of Slave in Redis

Tags: redis

When using the replication features of Redis in an environment with slaves of slaves, would the `connected_slaves` counter increase for the master, the slave which is acting as a master, or both? Refer to the example diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ugO0.jpg

In the image, there is a master with two slaves, each slave having its own two slaves. In this instance would the master's `connected_slaves` value be 6? Would the `connected_slaves` value of the first pair of slaves be 2 each?

I have looked through Redis's documentation and have found nothing describing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the solution, I set up a virtual environment with seven Redis servers running simultaneously. They were set with sequential port numbers, with the default Redis port (6379) instance being the master. I configured two instances to be slaves to Instance_6379, and configured two more slaves each for Instance_6380 and Instance_6381, respectively. I then checked the `redis-cli info` output of each, taking note of the `connected_slaves` metric.

Here is what I found:
Masters will only report those slaves that are DIRECTLY CONNECTED to them. Slaves of slaves will NOT count towards the total number of slaves connected to the master.

In the example image referenced in the question, the leftmost Redis server would have only two `connected_slaves` and each of its children would also show two `connected_slaves`.

I hope this answer will be of use to someone.